# copying files to s3 without the source folder name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
aws s3 cp ./ s3://my-static-sites/a-site-root --recursive --exclude "*" --include "dist/*"
```

Within my docker-based pipeline I'm trying to get the files in `dist/` in to the folder `a-site-root/` but I end up with `a-site-root/dist/index.html` etc.

How do I get *index.html* (and all my other files in `dist/`) in to `s3://my-static-sites/a-site-root/index.html` without the `/dist/` path segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the `dist` folder, just specify that as the source:

```
aws s3 cp dist s3://my-static-sites/a-site-root --recursive
```